# Порядок вызова метода parallel() и sequential() в Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Цитата из книги:

> «Под капотом» происходит установка булева флага, который указывает, что все следующие за parallel операции необходимо выполнять параллельно. Аналогично можно преобразовать параллельный поток данных в последовательный, вызвав для него метод sequential. Вам может показаться, что путем комбинирования этих двух методов можно добиться очень точного контроля над тем, какие операции при обходе потока данных производить параллельно, а какие — последовательно. Например, сделать что-то вроде:
> stream.parallel()
> .filter(...)
> .sequential()
> .map(...)
> .parallel()
> .reduce();
> Но приоритет всегда будет у последнего вызова parallel() или sequential(), который влияет на весь конвейер. В этом примере конвейер будет выполняться параллельно, поскольку последним в нем был вызов метода parallel().

Сбивает с толку первое предложение. Хочется раз и навсегда понять, влияет ли "место", с которого был вызван метод parallel()? Судя по тому, что написано далее, абсолютно неважно, в начале цепочки или перед последним метод он был вызван, все методы как до него, так и после, будут работать в параллельном режиме, главное, чтобы после него не был вызван метод sequential(). Также в связи с этим не понятно, в каких случаях стоит применять метод sequential()?

Буду премного благодарен, если поможете расставить все точки над "и" в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация потоков может отличаться в разных версиях и редакциях Java, но не может противоречить исходной документации.

Посему - обратимся к первоисточнику: [Java Stream Api parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Parallelism)

> The stream pipeline is executed sequentially or in parallel depending
> on the mode of the stream **on which the terminal operation is invoked**.

То есть - вся цепочка вызовов будет работать в том режиме, в котором созданный поток  подошел к [терминальной операции](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).
Приведенная цитата является правильной, использоваться будет будет последний вызов `parallel() / sequential()`

P.S. Хотя, конечно, хотелось бы иметь возможность менять режим работы хотя бы после `intermediate stateful operation`, как, например, `limit()` или `distinct()`

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Тогда не совсем ясно, зачем вообще нужен метод sequential()?

Comment: @Atamiq, смотрим в ту же документацию: ` The stream implementations in the JDK create serial streams unless parallelism is explicitly requested.` . Ключевое тут - "имплементации в JDK". Может быть огромное количество "сторонних" реализаций, которые предоставляют по умолчанию parallelStream. Или не документируют, какой именно поток они предоставляют. А вам по каким-то соображениям вот позарез нужно, чтобы обязательно был sequential.

Comment: признаться, подобная мысль "проскользала" в голове, но уверенности в ней не было. Теперь все стало ясно, спасибо вам за помощь.